# why do the 2 payment boxes not appear!? i''m so confused! (HTML JS)

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I decided to make a webshop! but when I tried putting in a second payment box it didnt work! I used the Paypal scripts [https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart?flowloggingId=8a47de0f82d54``](https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart?flowloggingId=8a47de0f82d54%60%60)

https://pastebin.com/icRRHUNy

```
code is above ^^
```

kind regards!

Comment: please post your code directly to question, no need of adding extra urls that can become invalid in future.

Comment: Hi! thank you I tried but it kept returning invalid code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PayPal JavaScript SDK:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
```

Should only be loaded once per page -- before rendering buttons, or from the `<head>` element

Get rid of line 91.

Also you have two divs with id `paypal-button-container`; the second one should be given a different id, and the function that renders to it updated with that id.

Probably best to change the second initPayPalButton function's name and its invocation on line 120 to be initPayPalButton2, as well.